# How can I show amounts from a table linking to columns of users

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, razor, web-applications

I have two tables, a users and a transactions.

```
Users             Transactions

| Id | Name  |   | Id | TranId  |UserId  | Amount |
| -- | ------|   | -- | ------  |------  | ------ |
| 1  | John  |   | 1  | 1       | 2      | -100   |
| 2  | Jane  |   | 2  | 1       | 1      |  100   |
```

I have a table where I want to show each transaction and show the amounts for each user.

I can group the transactions but I cannot seem to show the amount in the correct column.

With my current code, the under the Jane column it shows the 100 but for any other users it just shows "N/A"

My controller

```
using (var context = new SharedExpensesEntities())
{
    transactionsList = context.Transactions.ToList();
    usersList = context.Users.ToList();
}

var viewModel = new TransactionListModel
        {
            TransactionList = transactionsList.GroupBy(x => x.TranId)
                .Select(g => new Transaction
                {
                    Id = g.LastOrDefault().Id,
                    TranId = g.Key,
                }).ToList(),

            UserList = usersList
        };

foreach (var transaction in viewModel.TransactionList)
{
    foreach (var user in viewModel.UserList)
    {
        var userTransaction = transactionsList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == user.Id && t.TranId == transaction.TranId);

        if (userTransaction != null)
        {
            transaction.UserId = user.Id;
            transaction.Amount = userTransaction.Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

My cshtml:

```
<table class="table">
    <tr class="table-header">
        <th>
            Id
        </th>
        <th>
            TransId
        </th>
        @foreach (var user in Model.UserList)
        {
            <th>
                @user.Name
            </th>
        }
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model.TransactionList)
    {
        <tr class="user-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editUserModal">
            <th>@item.Id</th>
            <th>@item.TranId</th>

            @foreach (var user in Model.UserList)
            {
                <th>@(Model.TransactionList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == user.Id)?.Amount != null ? string.Format("{0:N2}", Model.TransactionList.FirstOrDefault(t => t.UserId == user.Id).Amount) : "N/A")</th>
            }
        </tr>
    }
</table>
```

Comment: Can you also add expected outcome that you would like to see on your web page?

Answer (score 0):

To generate

> a table where I want to show each transaction and show the amounts for each user

| TranId | John | Jane |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -100 | 100 |

your code can be simplified. The following uses the same general structure of your code.

Start with the `viewModel` variable:

```
viewModel = new TransactionListViewModel()
{
    GroupedTransactionList = transactionsList.GroupBy(tr => tr.TranId),
    UserList = usersList
};
```

where the class `TransactionListViewModel` is defined as:

```
public class TransactionListViewModel
{
    public required IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, Transaction>> GroupedTransactionList { get; set; }
    public required IEnumerable<User> UserList { get; set; }
}
```

`.cshtml` view

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="table-header">
            <th>
                TransId
            </th>
            @foreach (var user in Model.UserList)
            {
                <th>
                    @user.Name
                </th>
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (IGrouping<int, Transaction> trGroup in Model.GroupedTransactionList)
        {
            <tr class="user-item" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editUserModal">
                <td>
                    @trGroup.Key
                </td>
                @foreach (User user in Model.UserList)
                {
                    int? amount = trGroup.FirstOrDefault(tr => tr.UserId == user.Id)?.Amount;
                    <td>
                        @(amount.HasValue ? string.Format("{0:N2}", amount) : "N/A")
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```